# Receiving error while running pip list on ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I'm attempting to run pip list to check the versions of my python modules on Ubuntu 15.04.

I'm receiving the following error after it makes it part of the way through the list:

```
argparse (1.2.1)
characteristic (0.1.0)
chardet (2.3.0)
colorama (0.3.2)
configobj (5.0.6)
dnspython (1.12.0)
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-Cache (0.13.1)
Flask-Login (0.2.11)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.0)
Flask-Uploads (0.1.3)
html5lib (0.999)
hurry.filesize (0.9)
idna (0.9)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
Landscape-Client (14.12)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)
ndg-httpsclient (0.3.2)
PAM (0.4.2)
pip (1.5.6)
pyasn1 (0.1.7)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.5)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
PyMySQL (0.6.6)
pyOpenSSL (0.13.1)
pyPdf (1.13)
PyPDF2 (1.24)
pyserial (2.6)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 80, in run
    self.run_listing(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 142, in run_listing
    self.output_package_listing(installed_packages)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 151, in output_package_listing
    if dist_is_editable(dist):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 367, in dist_is_editable
    req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 299, in from_dist
    assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
AssertionError

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmp0YGnDq
```

I've attempted the answer in this question: [command "pip list" shows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682584/command-pip-list-shows-error)

But this does not resolve the issue.

**edit**

I've also done apt-get remove python-pip, and reinstalled.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is probably not enough information to debug that problem. Are you using only apt's version, or did you update `pip` or `setuptools` via `pip` or `easy_install` at some point? Also `pip --version` would be helpful.

Comment: @cel I'm running pip version 1.5.6, and no updates from pip or easy_install